# HIVE SQL how to reuse subquery multiple times

Tags: sql, hive, subquery, common-table-expression

**problem:** There is a complicated & time-consuming <**subquery**> which will be used multiple times with conditions.

**question:** is there a way to reuse it multiple times?

What i want is something like this:

```
WITH tem_table AS <SUBQUERY>

SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  ...
  coln
FROM
  (SELECT
    col1,
    join_col
  FROM
    tem_table
 WHERE
    condition_1
  )a
  
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
      col2,
      join_col
    FROM
      tem_table
    WHERE
      condition2
    )b
    ON a.join_col = b.join_col
    
    ...
    
    LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT
          coln,
          join_col
      FROM
        tem_table
      WHERE
        condition_n
      )n
      ON a.join_col = n.join_col
```

Comment: You already have the CTE in your query. Could you please elaborate more on what exactly you're looking for?

Comment: @Abishek VK  CTE seems will be deleted after the first query excucated on it

Comment: In that case, is it okay for you to create a view and reuse it?

Comment: @Abishek VK apparently no. Just as mentioned above that only first query have the chance. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use macros in hive.

One example is [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/create-user-defined-functions-in-hive-beeline-ff965285d735).

Comment: thx, maybe it will be helpeful but have no chance to test it.  cause the CUSTOMISED PLATFORM doesnt support macros -_-